# How do i make search bar appear and disappear upon clicking outside the appeared field in the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Working on adding search bar to my web page ,and on smaller screen there is search icon at the navbar , upon toggle it enables the search bar visibility in just below the navbar(first in the main content). Prior to this  toggling the search icon in the navbar makes the search bar visible in  just below the navbar,which is in the main content. There after clicking outside the search bar(input field) the search bar visibility is set to none . Now here is my issue encoutered ! When i toggle the search icon the search bar appears,so therefore any click outisde the search bar makes every content in the main content disappear ,which i want only the search bar visibility to be none excluding the rest. Below is my bootstrap codes

```
 ** Bootstrap codes**
```

```
<!------------------------------Main Content-------------------------->
<!-- Button trigger search panel . -->
<div class="container">
    <form action="GET" id="searchPanel">
        <div class="input-group mb-3 d-flex rounded-4" style="width:100%;" id="input">
           <div class="input-group-prepend">
               <span class="input-group-text d-block mx-auto"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass" id="searchIcon"></i></span>
           </div>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for....">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success ">Search</button>
       </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript implementation**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const searchIcon= document.getElementById('search');
    const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchPanel');
    const searchInput = document.getElementById('input')
    //Toggle search bar visibility
    searchIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(window.innerWidth < 992) {
            searchBar.style.display = (searchBar.style.display === 'block') ? 'none' : 'block'
       }
   });
   //Hide search bar clicking outside appeared search bar
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const clickInside = searchIcon.contains(e.target) || searchBar.contains(e.target);
        if(!clickInside) {
            searchBar.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the like below, I just gave you an idea but you have to implement it.

```js
// when a click has occurred then this event will be triggered
window.addEventListener(
    "click",
    (e) => {
      // I use div but you should use a container or hero section or another one that holds your entire elements like a section
      if (e.target.matches("div")) {
         // make display none or disable here...
         // I mean your next logic will be here..
      }    
    },
    true
  );
```